# Delphi: what is the way to stack several bottom-aligned controls?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi7 to create a status-bar in design time (from TBX package). During runtime, I create a "docked info line", which is a panel with `Align=alBOttom`.

The problem: Sometimes the info line appears above the status bar, and sometimes it's below the status bar.

What is the method to always show panel above the status bar?

Comment: Set the `Top` property of the control you want to be at the bottom to the height of the form every time you fear that something bad has happened.

Comment: That for sure is an exact dupe

Comment: After re-reading, yes, I agree.

Comment: Why would one of my perfectly fine comments come up missing? Now it makes my latest comment look very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When showing the panel (ie when you set it's `Visible` property to `True`) also set it's `Top` position above the statusbar (or set the statusbar's Top to below the panel)

```
Statusbar.Top := panel.Top + panel.Height;
```

Comment: Or `Statusbar.Top := ClientHeight + 1;` would be a bit easier, and not specific to any other controls.